# Как отключить все соединения пользователей с ms sql server с помощью osql?

Tags: sql-server, cmd

Есть необходимость исполнять sql скрипты, перед этим нужно закрыть все соединения для избежания ошибок, можно ли это с помощью osql?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201350/1216425

Comment: _"закрыть все соединения"_ - к инстансу или к конкретной БД? Если к БД, то проще перейти в SINGLE_USER: `ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`. Если нужен монопольный доступ к инстансу, то нужно сервис стартовать с параметром `-m`. Убитие соединений не гарантирует того, что новые соединения не будут установлены.